# Flutter - google_mobile_ads support facebook audience network mediation with admob?

Tags: flutter, admob, facebook-audience-network

i am trying Facebook Audience Network bidding in flutter with admob but i have confusion about plugin which ads plugin i use facebook or admob? according to my research i should to use admob plugin for Facebook Audience Network & Admob bidding Integration but which admob plugin ? [google_mobile_ads](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads)  this plugin support Bidding with Facebook Audience Network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes google_mobile_ads support Ads mediation with Facebook Audience Network,
you can find more here --
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/facebook

Comment: i need to integrate both admob and facebook plugins and place their ads unit & placement id?